# Does IE10+ have an XDomainRequest object?

Tags: internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

I know that IE10+ supports CORS using XMLHttpRequest, just like all other browsers do. However, what is less clear is whether the XDomainRequest object still exists in IE10+. In other words, what does calling `new XDomainRequest()` in IE10+ return (does it return nothing, a new XDomainRequest object, a new XMLHttpRequest object, or something else), and is the behavior the same for IE10 vs IE11?

P.S. I know this is something that can be easily verified with an IE browser, but a) I don't have access to a Windows machine and b) the [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are silent on the behavior.

EDIT: I wrote a function that I believe will reveal the answer, if someone would be so kind as to run it in IE10 and IE11 and report back: http://jsfiddle.net/Xck9K/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IE10 (and presumably IE11) still have the `XDomainRequest` transport object.  I verified myself in a real copy of IE10 running on Windows 7.  `window.XDomainRequest` reveals the constructor function.